# Get all files names in subfolders Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a below Folder Structure in Data lake,  I want to get all .csv file names from all subfolders of my ParentFolder directory. All my files are .csv files is there a simple approach to do using Metadata activity.

ParentFolder > Year=2020Folder

```
          2020-10-20Folder > 2020-10-20.csv

          2020-10-21Folder > 2020-10-21.csv

          2020-10-22Folder > 2020-10-22.csv
```

Comment: Hi @Raju, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

I've made a test to get the FileNames successfully.

I created the same file structure as yours.

[image]

1. In ADF, we can define an Array type variable to store the file names later.

[image]

2. It's the summary of the pipeline.

[image]

At the GetMetaData1 activity, let's define a DataSet of the root folder `2020Folder`. Then we use `Child Items` to get all the subfolders.

[image]

3. At the ForEach1 activity, we can use the expression `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` to foreach the Folder list.

[image]

4. In the ForEach1 activity, We can add dynamic content `@item().name` to pass the subfolder name to the GetMetadata2 activity. Then we can use the GetMetadata2 activity to get the `Child Items` from the subfolder.

[image]

[image]

5. At the Append variable activity, we can use the array variable **FileNames** we defined previously to store all the filenames. Here we use expression `@activity('Get Metadata2').output.childItems[0]` to get the filename.

[image]

6. In the end. We can define another Array type variable to store and review the result.

[image]

The output we can see the array.

[image]

Comment: In your step 4 where you are using @item().name, this would also impact the `GetMetadata1` activity. This means when you run the Pipeline it won't allow you to run as it would throw error.

Comment: this worked for me and I was able to load all files into the sql and deleted after load completed