# How to get files from a subfolder present under nested parent folder in azure data factory?

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory

My folder structure is like below,

Container/xx56585/DST_1/2021-03-26/xxxxxxxx.csv

Container/xx56585/DST_1/2021-03-26/xxxxxxxx.ctl

Container/xx56585/DST_2/2021-03-26/yyyyyyyyy.csv

Container/xx56585/DST_2/2021-03-26/yyyyyyyyy.ctl

Container/xx56585/DST_3/2021-03-26/zzzzzzzzz.csv

Container/xx56585/DST_3/2021-03-26/zzzzzzzzz.ctl

Container/xx56585/DST_4/2021-03-26/sssssssssss.csv

Container/xx56585/DST_4/2021-03-26/sssssssssss.ctl

I need to copy .csv and .ctl files to sFTP target and move these files to achieve folder(in the blob storage after copy activity)

Please help me on this

Comment: Joseph Xu:Please help me on this as it is similar to :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64504159/get-all-files-names-in-subfolders-azure-data-factory

Comment: Are your files all in `xx56585` folder?  Are there only two files in `2021-03-26` folder ?

Comment: Is `2021-03-26` folder dynamically generated?

Comment: Yes, There are 4 subfolders under a parent folder 'xx56585'.Each  subfolder will have <rundate> folders. We need to copy .csv and .ctl files present under this <rundate> folders. These folder are created by spark (Data bricks).

Comment: The 4 subfolders under the parent folder "xx56585" are fixed, right? ADF can only traverse one level.

Comment: Yes. It is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
We can use Get Metadata1 to check does the ctl file exist.
[image]
Add dynamic content `@concat('xx56585/',item(),'/',substring(adddays(utcnow(),-3),0,10),'/')` to the path.
[image]

---

I created a simple test to copy files under `<rundate>` folders to target folder.
My folder structure

```
Input/xx56585/DST_1/2021-03-26/xxxxxxxx.csv

Input/xx56585/DST_2/2021-03-26/yyyyyyyyy.csv

Input/xx56585/DST_3/2021-03-26/zzzzzzzzz.csv

Input/xx56585/DST_4/2021-03-26/sssssssssss.csv
```

Output:
[image]

1. Define an Array type variable `Array1` and assign the value `["DST_1","DST_2","DST_3","DST_4"]`.
   [image]
2. At `ForEach1` activity, we can add dynamic content  `@variables('Array1')` to traverse this array.
   [image]
3. Inside `ForEach1` activity, we can use Copy activity to copy files under the dynamic path via expression `@concat('xx56585/',item(),'/',substring(adddays(utcnow(),-3),0,10),'/')`.
   [image]
4. My current date is `2020-03-29` so I use `adddays(utcnow(),-3)` to get `2020-03-26` in the above steps.
   [image]

That's all.

Comment: Thank you very much Joseph. It is working .I need to copy .ctl files to sFTP along with .csv files. I do not think wildcard supports more than one parameters. After copy, need to move these .csv and .ctl files to archive folder. any suggestion on this?

Comment: @Sathishkumar Govindasamy You're right, wildcard doesn't support more than one parameters. Per my experience, we need two copy activities to copy .csv and .ctl files.

Comment: is there any way to copy corresponding .CSV  based on .ctl file sequentially instead copying all .CSV and .CTl together?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familary about .ctl file. Do you want to judge whether to copy this csv file based on the content of the ctl file?

Comment: .ctl file are control file only. Yes, need to judge the copy this csv file using ctl file only. Is there any option in adf to implement the same?

Comment: I feel difficult to answer this. I think we can use Get Metadata activity to to check does the ctl file exist. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can add filter activity in this before copy activity in which we can use substring function and find if file name contains **.ctl** or **.csv**